# Create linked data structures from array

Tags: java, linked-list

I am new to linked data structures and was wondering how to create an undirected graph when given 2 points from a 2d array and no weight determined between the points. I've searched around and couldn't really find what I was looking for.

**Example:**

```
int[][] points = { { 0, 1 },{ 0, 2 },{ 1, 2 },{ 1, 3 },{ 3, 4 } };
```

Drawn out it should look like this.

```
      0
      |
    -------
    |     |
    1-----2
    |
    3-----4
```

**EDIT**

I also want to be able to find the shortest path from 0 to 4 and traversing to each point at least once while counting each move along the way. There is the possibility that you may have to move backwards.  In above example, the shortest path from 0 - 4 is (0-2)(2-1)(1-3)(3-4) and counts to be 4 moves.

Comment: I'd start by actually thinking about what data structure you want to end up with and writing at least a dummy implementation. There are several possible representations for graphs, and they can be implemented differently, so it's not clear which one you want to build. (For instance, your original `int[][]` is already a perfectly valid graph data structure.)

Comment: Are you trying to read an edge list? Into what structure?

Comment: I just edited my question. Should be more clear on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a class **Node** that contains a list of adjacent nodes
2. Iterate through your nodes in the **points** array. Create a Node object for each node you find (probably it would be better to keep them in a Map at the beginning.
3. Iterate once again and fill the adjacent nodes list for each node.

Consider this class Node:

```
public class Node {
    private int id;
    private List<Node> adjacentNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public List<Node> getAdjacentNodes() {
        return adjacentNodes;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And this method creates a collection of all nodes and they're linked together:

```
 private static Collection<Node> createGraphNodes(int[][] pointsMatrix) {
    Map<Integer, Node> nodes = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
    for(int[] points: pointsMatrix) {
        for(int point: points) {
            if(nodes.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(point))) {
                continue;
            }

            Node node = new Node();
            node.setId(point);
            nodes.put(point, node);
        }
    }

    for(int[] points: pointsMatrix) {
        int nodeId1 = points[0];
        int nodeId2 = points[1];

        Node node1 = nodes.get(Integer.valueOf(nodeId1));
        Node node2 = nodes.get(Integer.valueOf(nodeId2));

        node1.getAdjacentNodes().add(node2);
        node2.getAdjacentNodes().add(node1);

    }

    return nodes.values();
```

Comment: I worked a lot to bring this answer so don't forget to accept if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way that I could possibly find a path between the nodes like what I explained in my edit? I really appreciate it.

Comment: The path algorithm you're looking for sound like a different question to me. I would open another post if I were you.

Comment: If I'm getting the question right it sounds pretty similar to the travelling salesperson problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

The difference here is that it is not a circular path and it can have repeartitions.

Comment: It is really a simplified version of TSP.

Comment: That's true, I don't have an answer for you (you started the question with the implemntation which I was able to provide a quick answer to).
If you decide to ask a new question please don't forget to accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic ways to represent graphs.

Adjacency matrix and adjacency lists. You can read about the adjacency matrix in wikiepdia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

To implement adjacency lists you create one list for each node and you put in the list all the nodes that the respective node is connected to.

Here is more on graph representations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to represent graphs is to use the Adjacency matrix, which is a two-dimensional boolean matrix in which rows and columns represent nodes in the graph, and the intersection between one row and column states if they are connected. It contains one if they are connected zero otherwise.

For example your above graph will be:

```
     0    1    2    3    4   
0   [0]  [1]  [1]  [0]  [0] 
1   [1]  [0]  [1]  [1]  [0]  
2   [1]  [1]  [0]  [0]  [0] 
3   [0]  [1]  [0]  [0]  [1]
4   [0]  [0]  [0]  [1]  [0]
```

Comment: Shouldn't array[1][3] have a [1] same with array[3][1]? and array[3][0] be 0? I'm just asking.

Comment: How would I go about going through the path and count each move? Sorry. Probably a stupid question. I just don't understand how I would implement in code.